# Insert a variable route path into nginx location configuration

Tags: nginx, regex

I have a simple user based storage for images where I have a main folder say 'users' and within it, my server creates variable folders to store images for each user. The string used for the folder is randomly generated. What I would like is to designate the random string on the path as a variable.

here is an example

say `root /myapp`

then within `/myapp/users/` there are `/user1` `/user2` `/user3` ... so on

I would like the expression to go something like `location /users/{{variableUser}}/cover`

Answer (score 3):

See this question on superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/330194/how-to-i-get-variables-from-location-in-nginx

Basically, you use regular expressions and capture the variable you need in your location block:

```
location ~ /users/([a-z0-9]+)/cover {
  # your "random string" will be captured in a variable named $1
}
```